# Why is Azure Application Gateway Returning a 502

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-container-instances

[image: Architecture]

As depicted above, I have a container running in ACI where it binds to two ports. That container talks to a database on :5432.

Using Azure Application Gateway, I have setup 2 listeners, 2 rules, and 2 backend settings to route https traffic over 443 to the two ports in the container.

The **admin.d.com resolves and works no problem**. The enroll.d.com returns a 502 Bad Gateway.

Since I have them setup the exact same way just with their different sub domains and ports, I'm at a loss. In the resource group / vnet, I don't have anything else running, this is a fresh instance.

Comment: What does the App Gateway backend health show? 99% of the time it's because of an unhealthy backend but you should be able to see the reason why.

Comment: @DusDee you were spot on. I wasn't tracking that if the health probe was failing, the Gateway would automatically give a 502 even if everything else was configured correctly. I made a custom health probe and am now past that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DusDee stated in the comments, my issue was due to the health probe failing. I created a custom health probe with parameters for my system (valid codes of 200-499) and the connection began working.